# SimpleXML Single Depth Element with Attribute in Inline List

Tags: java, xml, simple-framework

I want to parse the following XML

```
<entry key="9" type="9">
  <value>
    <amount stake="10">50000000</amount>
    <amount stake="1">5000000</amount>
    <winner>0.0</winner>
    <description>9 Correct Numbers</description>
  </value>
</entry>
```

I try to achieve this with the follow classes:

```
@Root(name="entry")
public class OddsEntryXMLObject {

    @Attribute(name="key")
    private String iKey;

    @Attribute(name="jackpot", required=false)
    private String iJackpot;

    @Attribute(name="type", required=false)
    private String iType;

    @Element(name="value")
    private OddsValueXMLObject iOddsValueXMLObject;
}

public class OddsAmountXMLObject {

    @Element(name="amount")
    private String iAmount;

    @Attribute(name="stake", required=false)
    private String iStake;
}
```

However I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.simpleframework.xml.core.ValueRequiredException: Unable to satisfy @org.simpleframework.xml.Element(data=false, name=amount, required=true, type=void) on field 'iAmount' private java.lang.String OddsAmountXMLObject.iAmount for class OddsAmountXMLObject at line 1
```

Anyone know how to parse this?

Comment: I replaced the `simplexml` tag with `java`, `xml` and `simple-framework`. SimpleXML is an extension in PHP which would attract PHP coders to your question. It's probably why it hasn't received much attention for months. There are so many questions on SO you'd want to get your tags right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no declaration for `OddsValueXMLObject` class in the code provided.
Assuming the declaration is what I think it is,
the error message basically means that it expects an `amount` element inside an `amount` element,
like this:

```xml
<amount>
    <amount></amount>
</amount>
```

Of course, there is nothing like that in the XML you have.
You can parse it with this instead:

```java
@Root(name="entry")
public class OddsEntryXMLObject{
    @Attribute(name="key")
    private String key;

    @Attribute(name="jackpot", required=false)
    private String jackpot;

    @Attribute(name="type", required=false)
    private String type;

    @Element(name="value")
    private OddsValueXMLObject value;
}

@Root(name="value")
public class OddsValueXMLObject{
    @ElementList(inline=true)
    private java.util.List<OddsAmountXMLObject> amounts;

    @Element(name="winner", required=false)
    private String winner;

    @Element(name="description", required=false)
    private String description;
}

@Root(name="amount")
public class OddsAmountXMLObject{
    @Attribute(name="stake", required=false)
    private String stake; 

    @Text
    private String text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find following working code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<entry key="9" type="9">
  <value>
   <amount stake="10">50000000</amount>  
     <!-  <amount stake="1">5000000</amount>     -->   
    <!-- <winner>0.0</winner>-->
    <!--<description>9 Correct Numbers</description> -->
  </value>
</entry>
```

1) I have commented amount since its same attribute so throwing error , you need to fix your sample xml.

2) winner and description is missing in your class.

3) you need to define one more class to get value .

4) Your Root element is missing**

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.Attribute;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;

  @Root(name="amount")
class OddsAmountXMLObject {

        @Element(name="amount")
        private String iAmount;

        @Attribute(name="stake", required=false)
        private String iStake;


}
```

other class

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.Attribute;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;

@Root(name="entry")
public class OddsEntryXMLObject {

   @Attribute(name="key") String iKey;

   @Attribute(name="jackpot", required=false)
   private String iJackpot;

   @Attribute(name="type", required=false)
   private String iType;

   @Element(name="value")
   private OddsAmountXMLObject iOddsValueXMLObject;
}
```

Test example

```
import java.io.File;

import org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister;

public class ParseExample {


    public static void main(String[] list) throws Exception {
        Persister persister = new Persister();
         File file = new File("C:\\Users\\290008812\\Jhipster_workspace\\Test\\src\\DOMParserDemo\\NewFile.xml");//My xml path
         OddsEntryXMLObject example = persister.read(OddsEntryXMLObject.class, file);

        //System.out.println(example.iKey);
        //System.out.println(example.amount2);

        persister.write(example, System.out);
    }




}
```

I am using "simple-xml-2.6.jar"

Result :

Since you have declared amount two time in xml getting error " Element 'amount' declared twice at line 6" so need to fix your xml structure

```
Exception in thread "main" org.simpleframework.xml.core.PersistenceException: Element 'amount' declared twice at line 6
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Variable$Adapter.read(Variable.java:444)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Variable$Adapter.read(Variable.java:422)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readVariable(Composite.java:679)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readInstance(Composite.java:627)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several `amount` elements so that indicates there is a list. This solution uses the javax.xml classes instead of the third party SimpleXml library. The `entry` class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="entry")
public class OddsEntryXMLObject {

    @XmlAttribute(name="key")
    private String iKey;

    @XmlAttribute(name="jackpot", required=false)
    private String iJackpot;

    @XmlAttribute(name="type", required=false)
    private String iType;

    @XmlElement(name="value")
    private OddsValueXMLObject value;
}
```

This holds a value class, though you can change this to a `List` if you want:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="value")
public class OddsValueXMLObject {
    @XmlElement(name="amount")
    List<OddsAmountXMLObject> amounts;

    @XmlElement(name="winner")
    private String dWinner;

    @XmlElement(name="description")
    private String sDescription;
}
```

This holds an `amount` class, with a `List` of amounts.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="amount")
public class OddsAmountXMLObject {
    @XmlValue
    private String iAmount;

    @XmlAttribute(name="stake")
    private String iStake;

}
```

You can test it with this code:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( OddsEntryXMLObject.class, OddsValueXMLObject.class, OddsAmountXMLObject.class  );
Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
JAXBElement<OddsEntryXMLObject> o = u.unmarshal( new StreamSource(getClass().getResourceAsStream("SimpleXML.xml")), OddsEntryXMLObject.class);


Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
m.marshal(o, System.out);
```

Which outputs the same xml as the input. These classes will also do a roundtrip using `schemagen` to create a `.xsd` file and `xjc` to compile the `.xsd` schema back to Java POJOs. After the roundtrip this field names will change because the annotations don't match original names, hence it is advised that you change the field (property) names to match the annotations.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: The `u.unmarshal( new StreamSource(getClass().getResourceAsStream("SimpleXML.xml")), OddsEntryXMLObject.class);` call parses the XML. What's the problem?

Comment: He was asking why he was getting an exception, not how to parse XML.